# Iterating over the list collection in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a simple list that returns results from the controller from the List collection.
Previously, I wrote each individual result from the list one by one, but I know that this is a bad practice according to the DRY principle. That's why I'm trying to change it.
I'm not friends with thymeleaf.

I care that:

- until the list is not empty, I created tables with results, as I did before. Only this time in the form of loops.
- then it is possible to choose one table which will then be saved in the repository, how should I do it? Using submit under each table?

Please help.
Thank you

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="css/font.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/chart.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Cheapest Flight</h2>


        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">

                <b><img th:src="@{'http://pics.avs.io/400/400/' + ${AirlineIataFirst} + '.png'}"></b>

        Bad code /////......

                <c><p th:text="'Airline:  ' + ${AirlineFirst}"/></c>
                <d><p th:text="'Price:  ' + ${PriceFirst}+ ${Currency}"/></d>
                <e><p th:text="'Departure:  ' + ${DepartureFirst} "/></e>
                <f><p th:text="'Return:  ' + ${ReturnFirst} "/></f>


            </a>
```

And what I'm trying to do :

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" th:if="${flight != null}" >

<b><img th:src="@{'http://pics.avs.io/400/400/' + ${AirlineIataFourth} + '.png'}"></b>


<li th:each="flights : ${flight}" th:text="${flight}"></li>
<li th:each="prices : ${price}" th:text="${price}"></li>
 <c><p th:text="'Airline:  ' + ${flight}"/></c>
 <d><p th:text="'Price:  ' + ${price}+ ${Currency}"/></d>
 <e><p th:text="'Departure:  ' + ${DepartureFourth} "/></e>
 <f><p th:text="'Return:  ' + ${ReturnFourth} "/></f>
```

Controller :

```
        model.addAttribute("Currency", flightDTO.getCurrency());
        model.addAttribute("flight", cheapFlyService.flightList(output));
        model.addAttribute("number", cheapFlyService.flightNumberList(output));
        model.addAttribute("return", cheapFlyService.returnAtList(output));
        model.addAttribute("departure", cheapFlyService.departureAtList(output));
        model.addAttribute("price", cheapFlyService.priceList(output));
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be valid HTML tags in the second case. Your `<a>` is never closed. Also, you should likely stay away from using things like `<b>` as it's very confusing (it's a deprecated way to bold text). Remove all of those types of tags as it's not valid HTML or just plain confusing.

Additionally, while it will work, the naming on the `th:each` is backwards.  You should be passing multiple flights, and refer to just one flight:

Controller:

```
    model.addAttribute("currency", flightDTO.getCurrency());
    model.addAttribute("flights", cheapFlyService.flightList(output));
    model.addAttribute("numbers", cheapFlyService.flightNumberList(output));
    model.addAttribute("returns", cheapFlyService.returnAtList(output));
    model.addAttribute("departures", cheapFlyService.departureAtList(output));
    model.addAttribute("prices", cheapFlyService.priceList(output));
```

HTML:

```
<th:block th:each="flight : ${flights}">
    <span th:text=${flight.number}" th:remove="tag">[Flight Number]</span> <!-- or whatever property is that the Flight class may have.  Note the scoping. -->
</th:block>
```

But the major feedback is that the complete HTML would depend on how you have your data modeled.  For example, if a flight has a property called `routes`, then you can iterate on `routes` with an inner loop in Thymeleaf.  Otherwise, you are adding separate lists to the model and you would just call the `toString` method on each:

```
<th:block th:each="departure : ${departures}">
    <span th:text=${departure}" th:remove="tag">[This is calling toString() on the objects in the list]</span>
</th:block>
```

General debugging tip: start with things that work and gradually add.  If something is broken and you are lost, take away everything until it works and re-add back in gradually until you find the culprit(s).